# Is there any way to get the ellipsis after the two line in Label?

Tags: user-interface, vue.js, nativescript

I am using The Label tag for displaying the product name but some time it could be big so i need to display the product in two lines but if it goes beyond that i need ellipsis (...) after that. Thanks in advance

I already have two lines need ellipsis
[Check out this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wloVw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can provide a directive from https://gist.github.com/EddyVerbruggen/8232252e3a4667e7e20916279f98d3fc

```
<Label maxLines="2" .. />
```

Comment: I'll try it and let you know